# Symfony: Why the isInitialized always is false?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I used doctrine query a user:

```
$customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DemoUserBundle:Customer')->find(1);
```

But i got the result:

> Customer {#1441 ▼
>     +**isInitialized**: false
>     -id: 1
>     -username: null
>     -nickname: null
>     -email: null
>     -salt: null
>     -password: null
>     -roles: null
>     -enabled: null
>     -lastLogin: null
>     -expired: null
>     -expiredAt: null
>     -created: null
>     -modified: null
>     -group: null
>     -ceilphoneCode: null
>     -avatar: null
>     -tasks: null
>     -applications: null
>     -companies: null
>     -creators: null
>     -images: null
>     -company: null
>     -store: Store {#1440 ▶}
>     -realName: null
>     -sex: null
>     -age: null
>     -belongCompany: null
>     -address: null
>     -career: null
>     -relationProducts: null
>     -attributes: null
>     -medias: null
>     -logs: null
>      …2
>   }

the result is not completed, where are other data of this user? why the isInitialized is false?

Comment: What about when you query the database for id=1?

Answer (score 4):

`isInitialized` is false because you get a `Proxy` object from the `EntityManager`. You probably loaded an entity with a `Customer` with id `1` as an association somewhere earlier inside your application. This related object was not fetch joined (not eagerly loaded) and as a result that same `Proxy` is now returned from your `EntityManager`. Normally `find` should return a fully loaded object.

Read also [this GitHub post](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5984) where a similar issue is discussed

Answer (score 4):

I added `fetch="EAGER"` to an other entity which called this entity and it is Ok for me.

Try `$customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DemoUserBundle:Customer')->find(1);`

and `$customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DemoUserBundle:Customer')->find(2);`

And you will understand.