# Foreign key fields returning null on doctrine querybuilder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, query-builder

I have this query:

```
    /**
     * @return []
     */

    public function classificacao(): array
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('cla')
        ->andWhere('c.ativo =1')
        ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Classificacao','cla', 'with', 'cla.cliente = c.id')
        ->orderBy('c.codigo')
        ->getQuery();

        return $qb->execute();

    }
```

but when i dump it the fields of the fk's entity return as null (and have value on the db):

[image]

if I select the 'c' Entity as well: `->select('cla, c')` it works but passes the whole 'Cliente' entity again:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here and how I can get the return of the first image with the actual values inside the cliente field?

*

**EDIT 06/nov**

*
I did what Jakumi said:

Classificacao.php:

```
/**
 * @var \Cliente
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cliente", inversedBy="classificacao", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cliente_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $cliente;
```

Cliente.php

```
    /**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Classificacao", mappedBy="cliente")
*/
private $classificacao;

...

public function getClassificacao()
{
    return $this->classificacao;
}
```

But now I'm getting this error:
[image]

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: Left join is when you take all rows from cla and join all column from the other table, so i am giessing your ON clause has no matches

Comment: The `Cliente` in the first image is a [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235431), it will be fetched lazily when accessed.

Comment: it works because the cliente.id and cliente.ativo fields return the values. and the second dump it's the same query, the only difference is that I select 'cla' and 'c'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, there are **multiple** things at work here, the combination of which lead to your problem.

#### 1. you're selecting the wrong entity first

Your function is (as far as I can tell) in the `ClienteRepository` (guessing here), because apparently `c` in the `$this->createQueryBuilder('c')` is associated with it. If you want `Classificao`-Objects, you should put that function into the `ClassificaoRepository`. Your left join will lead to the problem, that your rows that look like this (ignoring the select here):

```
cliente1, classificao1
cliente2, null                  --because there is nothing linked
cliente3, null                  --because there is nothing linked
cliente4, classificao4
...
```

but you only want `Classificao` objects, so you get the second column and those contain some `null`s. This is due to `leftJoin` which allows the second column to be null.

Either putting it into the `ClassificaoRepository` or explicitly changing the `from` (and leftJoin) will fix that. Since IMHO the function belongs inside the ClassificaoRepository, I won't go into detail on changing the `from` and instead tell you to put this code into a function in your `ClassificaoRepository`:

```php
// in ClassificaoRepository
return $this->createQueryBuilder('cla')
     ->leftJoin('cla.cliente', 'c')     // <-- this works btw
     ->andWhere('c.ativo=1')
     ->orderBy('c.codigo')
     ->addSelect('c')       // <-- technically optional, but might improve performance
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();
```

(using `->innerJoin` instead in your query would have removed the `null` *rows*, btw. in this query it's indirectly achieved though)

#### 2. doctrine's joins/relations and how this impacts the result set

the problem with `->leftJoin('App\Entity\Classificacao','cla', 'with', 'cla.cliente = c.id')` is, that doctrine has no idea, that `cla.cliente = c.id` means "get me **that** Cliente's Classificao", but it will treat it as "some custom join is added with some custom condition". This is why even adding `c` to the select will not give you the right structure, really. However, Doctrine absolutely recognizes `->leftJoin('c.classificaos', 'cla')` as "I want **that** Client's Classificao" - HOWEVER, you have to define the inverse side of that relation for that to work (I'm assuming OneToMany here, you can swap it with OneToOne if it's a one-to-one):

```php
// in your src/Entity/Cliente.php

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Classificao::class, mappedBy="cliente")
 */
private $classificaos; // if one-to-one, name it 'classificao'

// + getter
```

adding that field to the `Cliente` entity and using `->addSelect('c')` *should* also load the related entity. (no promises)

#### 3. lazy-loaded entities/relations

Finally, what you're seeing there as

> the fields of the fk's entity return as null (and have value on the db)

is actually - as msg pointed out - how doctrine handles lazy-loaded data. When you load lots of entities with lots of relations, you don't want all of the related entities to also be loaded if they're not needed (and their related entities perhaps). However, from a convenience and logic standpoint, when you access `$classificao->getCliente()` you don't expect the result to be neither just the id nor `null` (because the object is not loaded), you expect the `Cliente` object. Doctrine solves this by adding a proxy object, which is a drop-in replacement wrapper (so to speak) that will act as a placeholder.

In the output you can identify a proxy object by the small `^` at the end of the class name `Cliente^` (the actual class name is different though, you can hover over it to see that) and also by the `__isInitialized__` property, that is set to `false` in your example. That property tells, that the *wrapped* object has NOT been loaded yet.

Now, doctrine's proxy objects are "smart" enough and they have the data they already know, namely the id (because that one's internally stored in the `Classificao`-object) and in this case `ativo` because you selected on that.

As soon as you try to access any other property on that, like `$classificao->getCliente()->getCnpj()`, the object will be loaded from the database, and all missing fields will be filled. There are only a few things that don't trigger the (late) lazy-loading, and `dump`ing is one of those things, serialization might also not trigger this, and some few other things.

You might try this to see it's true:

```
dump($classificao); // output with proxy not initialized
$classificao->getCliente()->getCnpj();
dump($classificao); // output with proxy initialized and all values loaded
```

When the object is loaded, the proxy will act as a proxy (duh) / wrapper, i.e. every call/access made to it will be forwarded to the wrapped (original) object.

You can force eager-loading (meaning, when you load entity A you simultaneously load entities B related to it) by adding the `fetch="EAGER"` attribute to the annotation (like in [the question/answer msg mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235431)), which will always* load the related entity alongside (* limitations do apply).

#### side note on the n+1 problem

A side note on lazy-loading: You might - in certain instances - explicitly trigger eager loading in the query to avoid the n+1 problem, which is: you load a lot of Classificao objects with one query and then access each of their `->getCliente()` method, each of which trigger a database query, thus you have the first query for the Classificao objects and *n* queries for the Cliente objects (hence the name n+1). The way to select - described in 1. above - *should* avoid this (not quite certain, tbh). Anyway: consider reading up on the ORM performance traps to avoid: https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/5-doctrine-orm-performance-traps-you-should-avoid

Comment: thanks for the explanation Jakumi. I've changed my query to the ClassificacaoRepository as you advised but now how can I return all the Clientes i have, even if there's no Classificacao for them. 
and also I've tried the - $classificao->getCliente()->getCnpj();
dump($classificao); - you've mentioned but it returns an error "Call to a member function getCliente() on array".

Comment: I'm not familar with the language "classificao" stems from, I was under the impression it was singular. so, for *one* classificao you should call `$classificao->getCliente()->get...` but apparently you have an array of `Classificao`, which means you may have to iterate through them to do that. To just fetch all Clientes (regardless of classificao) you might do `ClientesRepository->findAll()` to fetch the `Classificao` alongside (if they exist) you might use your original query, but instead of your join `->leftJoin('c.classificao', 'cla')` and don't just `->select` but `->addSelect('cla')`

Comment: thanks Jakumi, tried that but I cant do that kind of leftJoin because my cliente ('c') doesn't have a classificacao field. I need to change the relation of them on my db? so instead of Classificacao have a many to one with Cliente, Cliente have a many to one with Classificacao?

Comment: have a look at **2.** in my answer. you  have to add `inversedBy="classificao"` to Classificao.cliente

Comment: Did that but now I'm getting a circular reference error. I edited my question with the error and what I've changed on my entities. Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: @LucasMarques this is a different problem. what happens is, that it "works", but your output being generated isn't stopped. classificao references a client which references classificao and so on. serializing that won't work mindlessly, you have to stop the infinite recursion/referencing when serializing, if you're using the symfony serializer, take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes. short-term solution could be to make the new getters *private*